# what is the value of the following sum?

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to get the value of the following:
$$ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom {n}{2k} 5^k. $$
This comes from the computation of the trace of certain matrix.

Answer (score 10):

$$ \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom {n}{2k} (\sqrt{5})^{2k} +  \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom {n}{2k+1} (\sqrt{5})^{2k+1} = (1+\sqrt{5})^n$$

$$ \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom {n}{2k} (\sqrt{5})^{2k} -  \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom {n}{2k+1} (\sqrt{5})^{2k+1} = (1-\sqrt{5})^n$$

Comment: In fact, I was trying to find the value of $ [ (1+ \sqrt{5})/2 ]^n + [(1- \sqrt{5})/2]^n .$

Comment: @hkju ah ok, so I am reversing your work...anyway, it may be interesting for others...I doubt if your expression can be further simplified...

Comment: The sequence is A000032 or A000204 in OEIS.

Comment: @hkju Yeah, it's also related to Fibonacci numbers